# Saving file based on multiple cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have a macro save a file under a new name based off of certain cell values (of Merged Cells D2:G2 , and D1:G1 if that matters I am not sure).  I am newer and do not fully know how to get this to work. the path to the folder I am looking to have this macro save the files in is "  G:\PRODUCTION\Service  "  and I am not sure where to insert that into the code either.

Currently the VBA I am using is the below, and I am not sure how to edit it to actually function the way I need it to.

```
Sub SaveAsA1()
ThisFile = Range("D2").Value & Range("D1").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile
End Sub
```

Comment: You need the full path to save the file. See if `Filename:="G:\PRODUCTION\Service\" & ThisFile` works for you

Comment: So I replaced the Filename:=ThisFile with the bit you suggested (hopefully that was the right place to put it) but I get an error saying "  Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed.

Comment: Did you validate the path & filename? (Use `Debug.Print`)

Comment: Is the code in the workbook you're trying to save? What is the name of the worksheet that contains the cells `D1` and `D2`? What exactly is in those cells?

Comment: So the file name of the current file is "CARBIDE SHARPENING CHECK IN SHEET" that file path is correct. D2 = "TEST" D1= "04-28-22" as their values. I am trying to get the file to save a new file with a name of what is in D2 and D1 in that file path, which is the correct one... I am now thinking I am using the entirely wrong type of code.